# How to use str_replace_all with conflicting values

Tags: r, stringr

Example:
I have a string containing `one and two` and I would like to change it to `two and one`. Is there a way to do this with `str_replace` (or `str_replace_all`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `str_replace` with capture groups:

```r
x <- "one and two"
output <- str_replace(x, "(\\w+) and (\\w+)", "\\2 and \\1")
output

[1] "two and one"
```

Answer (score 0):

Base `R` option using `gsub` which swaps the words before and after " and " like this:

```r
string <- "one and two"
gsub("(.*) and (.*)", "\\2 and \\1", string)
#> [1] "two and one"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using stringr

```
library(stringr)

str="one and two"
str_c(rev(str_split(str, " ")[[1]]), collapse=" ")
```

```
[1] "two and one"
```